# How to generate MIPS assembly code from a Python parser program

Tags: python, mips

I have a parser I have programmed in Python and I need to generate the MIPS assembly code for this program with a MIPS framework surrounding the final output of the MIPS. How can I generate the MIPS assembly code from running my Python program?

Comment: Are you looking for the assembly code of all of the instructions generated in the course of the execution of Python running your parser code, or are you looking for equivalent MIPS code to the parser you wrote? The former is probably not going to be extremely helpful (as it'll be mostly traces of Python's internals)...

Comment: Yes, the assembly code of all the instructions generated by running the Python parser code.